# Connect to remote MSSQL server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to connect to a remote database server with PHP to query and return data.

So far, I have tried this:

```
$connection = mssql_connect('[redacted]:1433\SQLEXPRESS', '[redacted]', '[redacted]');
```

and

```
$connection = mssql_connect('[redacted]', '[redacted]', '[redacted]');
```

Both result in FALSE, but no error thrown. What am I missing? It doesn't even seem to attempt to connect (fails very quick).

Comment: do you remember who did you solve this ?

Comment: I used FoxPro MSSQL to MySQL conversion software to convert it to MySQL, then set up the database side by side and did the migration. Fooling with MSSQL was eating way too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good answer by AlexC, but what I wound up doing was converting the MSSQL database over to MySQL and performing the migration with the Migrate framework (Drupal).

Answer (score 1):

Usually this isn't so much about the connection code as the setup of the external DB server.  First try this:
`$connection = mssql_connect('[redacted]\SQLEXPRESS', '[redacted]', '[redacted]');`
But you are connecting to SQL Express which by default doensn't accept any incoming TCP/IP requests, so if that doesn't work out, you'll need to check the configuration (or if it's truly external, have the DBA check it) and make sure:

- it's set up to accept TCP/IP requests,
- that the firewall is allowing that IP and port through, and
- that the specific IP address your request is coming in on is accepting requests